# Re-writing basic AngularJS (1.4) Code to account for breaking change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Newbie at Angular here... I'm currently following the Dan Wahlin tutorial on Youtube and have reached the part involving controllers, but for some reason I've got a major issue getting this to work...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="sCtrl">
    Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function sCtrl($scope){
        $scope.customers=[
          { name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York' },
          { name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix' },
          { name: 'Dan Jones', city: 'Tuscon' },
          { name: 'Jane Smith', city: 'Chicago' },
          { name: 'Danielle Jones', city: 'New Orleans' }
        ];
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm following what he's done, and everything seems to be in order... Previous examples Dan's performed on the video I've been able to replicate, but now this doesn't seem to work... I've heard that there's some sort of "breaking change" that's been introduced from versions 1.3 and above, but I can't seem to follow the fixes with respect to my current code... I'm currently using AngularJS v1.4.

How would I re-write this code to counter this breaking change that's been experienced here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare a valid module and declare controller in it using syntax `angular.module('yourAppName').controller('sCtrl', sCtrl($scope){...});`. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-scope-object)

Changes in html are:

```
<html data-ng-app="youAppName">
```

And in script section it should be

```
  var app = angular.module('yourAppName', []);
  app.controller('sCtrl', sCtrl);
  function sCtrl($scope){
    $scope.customers=[
      { name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York' },
      { name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix' },
      { name: 'Dan Jones', city: 'Tuscon' },
      { name: 'Jane Smith', city: 'Chicago' },
      { name: 'Danielle Jones', city: 'New Orleans' }
    ];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

from what I see you should have `angular.module('app', []).controller('sCtrl', sCtrl);` and in your html: `ng-app="app"`

Answer (score 1):

Angular is being updated to enforce a few best practices that are widely in use. Angular 1.4 already requires you to specify a module via `ng-app` and explicitly add a controller to that module. One breaking change expected for version 2.0 is the deprecation of the `$scope` service in favor of named controllers bound with `this`. Here's a version of the example using a named controller instead of `$scope`:

```
<body data-ng-app="example">
  <div data-ng-controller="sCtrl as sctrl">
    Name: <input type="text" data-ng-model="sctrl.name" />
    <ul>
      <li data-ng-repeat="cust in sctrl.customers | filter:sctrl.name | orderBy:'city'">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module("example", [])
      .controller("sCtrl", function sCtrl() {
        this.customers=[
          { name: 'John Doe', city: 'New York' },
          { name: 'John Smith', city: 'Phoenix' },
          { name: 'Dan Jones', city: 'Tuscon' },
          { name: 'Jane Smith', city: 'Chicago' },
          { name: 'Danielle Jones', city: 'New Orleans' }
        ];
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Try it on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CBwYG5h9r6OD5e1YceAx?p=preview).

Comment: Hey Austin... uh, your code on Plunker does not appear to work... entering the name in the input field doesn't seem to filter any of the list...?

Comment: That's because I forgot to change the filter to `filter:sctrl.name`. Thanks for the comment!